# The correct way to pass changeable string to a class instance in C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
  public MyClass(string s)
  {
    _s = s;
  }

  string _s;
}
```

Now I want this class remember the value of s string the way whenever it's changed in the code instantiated this class, the stored _s value reflects the change.

The obvious way is to create a wrapper class like StringContainer which will have a single property holding a string and pass the instance of this wrapper class instead of just the string (so that both the caller and MyClass instance always work with StringContainer.s, not s directly).

However, it seems a bit heavy solution, I'm curious if anything nicer exists? Maybe there is a built-in C# construct for that? Like 'ref' modifier when you need to pass something by reference in a method call. Maybe some kind of generic type wrapper like Nullable to enable creating such wrappers with less code?

In the end, it's actually not about strings only, it's about passing a pointer instead of just the value for any type, be it string, object, int, etc. For instance:

- Create an object in the caller and assign it to a variable
- Pass the variable pointing referencing this object to MyClass instance
- In the caller, assign another object to the variable
- Result: MyClass instance automatically 'sees' the new value of the object

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the original variable went out of scope while `MyClass` is still accessible? Basically, there's nothing in C# to help you with this - even the C# 7 ref local and ref return wouldn't help, as far as I'm aware. You can easily create a `Wrapper<T>` though.

Comment: Thanks. I created my own wrapper myself and it seems to fit my needs.